# Copying data from form1.richTextBox to form2.richTextbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a Time clock for fun and to learn C#.

I have the time down, and the start, stop, clear.

However I am having issues with a "Notes" section. Ideally I'd like to be able to write notes into a field, and have an "Edit" button to allow the user to open a window for more options relating to text editing. (with the text from the Form1 rich text box)

My issue comes from copying the data from one form to another.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PunchOut
{
public partial class PunchOut : Form
{
    public PunchOut()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    int i = 0;
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        i++;

        TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i);

        textBox2.Text = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}",
                                        t.Hours,
                                        t.Minutes,
                                        t.Seconds);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox2.Text = ("00:00:00").ToString();
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form2().Show();
        richTextBox1.Text = Form2.richTextBox1.Text;

    }
}
}
```

Here is the Form2 code:

```
namespace PunchOut
   {
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
       public Form2()
       {
            InitializeComponent();
       }

        public void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = PunchOut.richTextBox1.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, I get an error that states:

> an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PunchOut.PunchOut.richTextBox1'

and

> an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PunchOut.Form2.richTextBox1'

Why do I get these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lots of unneeded work going on there.  I hope I explained this well enough

Breakdown:
We add a String Member Variable so that we can put the contents of a RichTextBox  into a string and pass that instead of using the RichTextbox control. 
We change the constructor to take a string parameter which is the RTF text that you want to change. Now Form2 can change any RTF text and not be specifically tied to just the richTextbox1 on the punchoutForm.

We then change the updating of the member variable to when the form is closing otherwise you are changing it with each keystroke which is a lot of unnecessary method calls.

```
namespace PunchOut
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
         public String richText;
         public Form2(String rText)
         {    
              InitializeComponent();
              this.richTextBox1.Rtf = rText;

         }

        private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            richText = this.richTextBox1.Rtf;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your button4_Click.  Use Rtf to include the codes otherwise just use a plain textbox

Now in your button click event handler we create a new form and assign it to a variable.  We then call showdialog.  The reason for showdialog is that this will make the form the top most form so that a user cannot go back to the punchout form and make a change to the richtextbox which would then make the text in the Form2 obsolete as it would no longer represent the correct RTF text in the punchout form.  When the user is done editing the text and closes the form we then request the edited rtf text by accessing the richText Member Variable of Form2.  The reason you can access this after the form has closed is that the form is not disposed until the method returns, your local variable lives within the scope of the method.

```
public void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{              
    Form2 f2 = new Form2(richTextBox1.Rtf);
    f2.ShowDialog();
    richTextBox1.Rtf= f2.richText;
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Sorceri, it may be of value to update your answer to explain why you've changed `Form2` so it doesn't need to know about `PunchOut` - it's probably hard for the asker to understand the advantages of your decoupled approach without more explanation.

Comment: @@Thegluestickman - you are right I did remove the things that should not have been there...the things you should have picked up on.

Comment: When I use this method I get this error 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult' to 'PunchOut.Form2' '

Comment: updated the code so showdialog was not on the same line as the instantiation of f2 in button4_Click handler.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't make a new reference to PunchOut in Form2. In your form 2 add this under the class declaration:

```
PunchOut punchOut;
```

And you get in Form2:

```
namespace PunchOut
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
       PunchOut punchOut;

       public Form2(PunchOut PUNCHOUT)
       {
            punchOut = PUNCHOUT;
            InitializeComponent();
       }

        public void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = punchOut.richTextBox1.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

In the original replace button4_CLick with:

```
public void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
        form2.Show();
        richTextBox1.Text = form2.richTextBox1.Text;

}
```

EDITED: You should pass the old PunchOut instead of creating a new one. I've updated the code.

You could store the text in a more accessible string. Then have your other form call that string.

```
public string yourText;

// down further

yourText = textBox1.Text;
```

Comment: Hmm, I still get the error that "an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PunchOut.Form2.richTextBox1' "

Comment: Did you use the new variable name? Because I forgot too. It's been updated.

Comment: Sorry, I mismatched the variables, I added the new punchOut to the wrong side. It should work now.

Comment: it seems to work on form2 now, however I still get this: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' to 'PunchOut.PunchOut'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: richTextBox1.Text = Form2.richTextBox1.Text; -still gives the object reference error however.

Comment: Hm, I thought since PunchOut inherits Form, it would work. Regardless, in the Brackets after "Public Form2" change "Form" to "PunchOut"

Comment: Hey that worked! Just have the object reference error. Do I need to reference Form2 in PunchOut (or Form1)?

Comment: Aha! In button4_Click put this:

'Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);'

'form2.Show();'

'richTextBox1.Text = form2.richTextBox1.Text;'

You need to assign Form2 to a variable before you can use it, because it is not "static" you need to create a new instance.

What was happening was:
You made a new Form2 and showed it, however it was not assigned to a variable.
You then tried to call Form2's by itself, which you can't do unless the class is static or you create a new instance. I hope I explained that well enough.

Sorry, you can't edit after 5 minutes. I accidentally hit enter to get a newline

Comment: aww yeah, totes worked. The only issue that I noticed was that Form2.RichTextbox1 was not editable because it was '=' to what punchout.richTextBox1 was. Comment that out and it will copy the information correctly. thanks so much! You explained it very well too!

Comment: If you need a hand with anything feel free to send me an email @ thegluestickman@gmail.com

Comment: Although this works, it's not good practice to pass an instance of `PunchOut` to `Form2`. If all `Form2` needs from `PunchOut` is the text, just pass the text (as in [Sorceri](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1586390/sorceri)'s answer). This reduces [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) and makes `Form2` independent of `PunchOut`, which it should be.

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie No offence to Sorceri, but he changed a lot of the existing code without explaining why he should be doing it like that. Also, in my answer you'll see I suggested storing the text in a string value.

Comment: @Thegluestickman very true - it's always confusing when an answer doesn't explain _why_. I did notice the bit about storing a string value, but it's still very important to emphasize that `Form2` shouldn't know about `PunchOut`...